# How to show a recieved message from TCPclient to MessageBox in TCPserver?

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcplistener

I'm creating a school project that is about receiving a string from a client and comparing it with a text in a text file. I have created everything but i can't figure out how to show the string that coming from the client to the server in a MessageBox. this MessageBox will contain an image passed on which number the user entered and it will also contain a congrats message like Congratulation (Name), you have won the (prize), you can collect it from (City).
MessageBox will contain in this order:

Prize image.

Congrats message.

where to collect the prize.

---

Do i need a new form in the WinForms so i can customize it to act like a messagebox?

Any tips would be appreciated;

Comment: Services running on a Windows system (server or not) have no access to login session and web servers run as a server. You'll need a user application that communicates with the web site itself and listens for events from the server (Signal R can make this easier).

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear in my information earlier. the server is also a TCPserver.

Comment: Your TCP client needs the instance of the Windows Form to get access to the existing form.  You can pass "this" (form instance) to the tcpclient class if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean? @jdweng

Comment: I'm not sure where you are having an issue.  First, from you receive code do you know how to write to the textbox? Second, Do you know how to parse the received text to get the results?

Comment: There is no textbox. the incoming message is like A000000-C000000 where the first part before the (-) is the customer number and the 2nd one is the card number. when i get this i will need to write that to file and split the line so i can use the customer number and compare it and see if it exists in the list that contain all the informations. the 2nd thing you asked is not going to work i think because the result will be shown in a pop up window with an image, name of the customer and which city to get the prize from. hope i answered you write :)